# Responsive CSS dropdown menu issue

Tags: css, menu, dropdown, responsive

My dropdown CSS menu works fine when I open it in mobile view, but stays there when I resize the window in my browser. When I try to get rid of it in my CSS media query, the dropdown doesn't work at all..

```js
function showmenu(){
 var menu = document.getElementById('mobile-menu'), maxH="148px";
 if (menu.style.height == maxH){
  menu.style.height = "0px";

 }else{
  menu.style.height = maxH;
 }
}
```

```css
@media(max-width: 1024px){
 .col-tab1{
 width: 8.33333333333%;
 float: left;
 }

 .col-tab2{
  width: 16.6666666667%;
  float: left;
 }

 .col-tab3{
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
 }

 .col-tab4{
  width: 33.3333333333%;
  float: left;
  
 }

 .col-tab5{
  width: 41.6666666667%;
  float: left;
 }

 .col-tab6{
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
 }

 .col-tab7{
  width: 58.3333333333%;
  float: left;
 }

 .col-tab8{
  width: 66.6666666667%;
  float: left;
 }

 .col-tab9{
  width: 75%;
  float: left;
 }

 .col-tab10{
  width: 83.3333333333%;
  float: left;
 }

 .col-tab11{
  width: 91.6666666667%;
  float: left;
 }

 .col-tab12{
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
 }
 
 .mobile{
 display: none;
 }

 .desktop{
  display: none;
 }
 
 .tablet{
  display: block;
 }

 #nav-toggle{
  width:50px;
  float:right;
  color:white;
  margin:25px;
  display:block;
 }
 
 
 nav ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin:auto;
  width:500px;
  height:100%;
  display:none;
 }
  
  #mobile-menu{
    display:none;
    }

}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav>
   <a href="#" id="nav-toggle" class="menu example5"><span onclick="showmenu('mobile-menu')"></span></a>
   <div id="nav-logo">
    <div id="bar1"></div>
    <div id="bar2"></div>
    <div id="bar3"></div>
    <div id="bar4"></div>
    <div id="bar5"></div>
    <div id="bar6"></div>
    <div id="bar7"></div>
   </div>
   <ul>
    <a href="#"><li><p>ABOUT</p></li></a>
    <a href="#"><li><p>WORK</p></li></a>
    <a href="#"><li><p>SERVICES</p></li></a>
    <a href="#"><li><p>CONTACT</p></li></a>
   </ul>
  </nav>
  <div id="mobile-menu">
   <ul>
    <a href="#"><li><p>ABOUT</p></li></a>
    <a href="#"><li><p>WORK</p></li></a>
    <a href="#"><li><p>SERVICES</p></li></a>
    <a href="#"><li><p>CONTACT</p></li></a>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: your media query doesn't actually work at all, it shows up on my screen and my screen is 1366px wide

Comment: you should use something like @media only screen and (max-width:768px) if you only want it to show on mobile devices (768 is ipad, but iphone is 320 and most androids are around 480, but growing to the 640 mark

Comment: If I want the div to be hidden when the screen is 1024px or bigger, I do @media(max-width:1024px){ mobile-menu { display:none; } ?

Comment: well, that doesn't work, like i said. use '@media only screen and (min-width:1024px){your code here}' to specify desktop media css but your default css will take effect if you just use the first media query (the max-width:768px one) to specify your mobile css and then don't bother with the min-width thing

Comment: did you fix your issue?